# Swift 3: completionHandler in session.dataTask not being called

Tags: swift, rest, closures

I am trying to make an API call using `dataTask`. I have a simple completion handler that, right now, is only used to test functionality. Even though I am using `task.resume()`, the task does not seem to be executing as the print statement never appears on the console. Furthermore, when I put a breakpoint in the handler, the breakpoint is skipped.

```
let requestURL : URL = URL(string : baseURL + requestType)!
let currentURLRequest : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
var request : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

let currentSession = URLSession.shared
var responseData : Data = Data()
let task = currentSession.dataTask(with: currentURLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        responseData = data!

        print("Closure has been called")
    })
task.resume()

// responseData never gets reassigned, print statement never executes
```

If I am calling `task.resume()`, why isn't the closure being called?

Comment: Apart from the issue you don't need an URL request at all for the GET mode. Just pass the URL. And you will never be able to use `responseData` outside the closure..

Comment: Pass the URL to what?

Comment: To `dataTask(with:`. The task can take both URL and URLRequest.